# Swapping two records in Oracle based on an order column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Simplifying, I have a table with a primary key and a sorting column:

```
TABLE P
----------
id   order
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

Suppose I want to "move up" the record with id 2, that is to swap the order value between that record and the record with order 1 so to get:

```
TABLE P
----------
id   order
1    2
2    1
3    3
```

In MySQL I used to do:

```
UPDATE 
    P AS P1,
    P AS P2
WHERE
    P1.id = some_id
AND P2.order = P1.order -1;
```

In Oracle this doesn't work.

EDIT
To clarify, given in input an id (given_id), I want:

```
SELECT order INTO :oldorder FROM P WHERE id=given_id;
UPDATE P SET order=order+1 WHERE id=given_id;
UPDATE P SET order=order-1 WHERE order=:oldorder.
```

That is, swapping the order field for two records, one is identified by the `given_id` and the other is the one that has the destination order value.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE p
   SET order = (case when id = 2 then 1 else 2 end)
 WHERE id IN (1,2)
```

would work.

Comment: How can this work? It's not generalized, it works with id 1 and 2 only!

Comment: @vulkanino - You'd clearly need to replace the values `1` and `2` with the values you want to swap.  I'm not clear what you are trying to generalize

Comment: The 1 and 2 was just an example. Given in input an id I want to swap its order field with the record having `order+1`. I try to clarify editing my question.